# Can we create a class that is not met to be used to create objects?

Tags: python, object

I'd like to create an object to regroup a set of functions (a sort of toolbox), tough I did not find how to create an object without creating a class. 
So, is it OK to create a class, let's say named `Toolbox`, such as `Toolbox.tool1(x)` applies a certain function to `x`, but `Toolbox()` gives an error ?

Otherwise, do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
class Toolbox(object):

  @property
  def __init__(self):pass

  @staticmethod
  def tool1(x):
    return x
```

When trying to [instantiate](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/classes_and_objects_I.html) `Toolbox`, i.e. doing `Toolbox()`, you will get an error, *as desired*, because of the [`property` decorating function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work), see

```
>>> Toolbox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

and [static methods](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod) can be used as usual, e.g.

```
>>> Toolbox.tool1(2)
2
```

Comment: Yes static methods are the way to go!

Comment: Also, you can use class methods via `@classmethod` decorator, if you need some shared functionality.